# Why console.log() gives output two times in createServer()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have written the following code in Node, when I start the server and refresh the page, line 1 prints 2 times.

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    {
        response.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "text/html" });
        response.write("<h1>Welcome to Node server</h1>");
        console.log("ksdguf");//1
        response.end();
    }
});

server.listen(3000);
console.log("Server started, Access it using browser");
```

Please someone explain what could be the possible reason behind this.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in the the question to give a definite answer. Have you tried in different browsers? I'm assuming you'll get this with Chrome. Try log `request.method`. I'm guessing you are getting both a `GET` and an `OPTIONS` request if this is happening in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because most browsers make a request for the favicon:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
{
    response.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "text/html" });
    response.write("<h1>Welcome to Node server</h1>");
    console.log("ksdguf");//1
    console.log(request.method);
    console.log(request.url)
    response.end();

}
});


server.listen(3000);

console.log("Server started, Access it using browser");
```

**Output:**

Server started, Access it using browser

undefined

ksdguf

GET

/

ksdguf

GET

/favicon.ico